# How to copy a Excel Sheet into another Workbook using Apache POI for Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to copy a Excel sheet into another Excel Workbook. All the possibilities I found browsing the web won't work with formulars.

The best code I found: http://www.coderanch.com/t/420958/open-source/Copying-sheet-excel-file-excel

Do you have any ideas how I can get this to work?

Thanks,
Lomin

Edit: Added the Code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

  /**  
   *  
   * @author jk  
   * getted from http://jxls.cvs.sourceforge.net/jxls/jxls/src/java/org/jxls/util/Util.java?revision=1.8&view=markup  
   * by Leonid Vysochyn   
   * and modified (adding styles copying)  
   * modified by Philipp Löpmeier (replacing deprecated classes and methods, using generic types)  
   */ 
  public final class Util {   

        /**
         * DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR.
         */
        private Util() {}

      /**
       * @param newSheet the sheet to create from the copy.
       * @param sheet the sheet to copy.
       */
      public static void copySheets(HSSFSheet newSheet, HSSFSheet sheet){   
          copySheets(newSheet, sheet, true);   
      }   

      /**
       * @param newSheet the sheet to create from the copy.
       * @param sheet the sheet to copy.
       * @param copyStyle true copy the style.
       */
      public static void copySheets(HSSFSheet newSheet, HSSFSheet sheet, boolean copyStyle){   
          int maxColumnNum = 0;   
          Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap = (copyStyle) ? new HashMap<Integer, HSSFCellStyle>() : null;   
          for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {   
              HSSFRow srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);   
              HSSFRow destRow = newSheet.createRow(i);   
              if (srcRow != null) {   
                  Util.copyRow(sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);   
                  if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {   
                      maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();   
                  }   
              }   
          }   
          for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {   
              newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));   
          }   
      }   

      /**
       * @param srcSheet the sheet to copy.
       * @param destSheet the sheet to create.
       * @param srcRow the row to copy.
       * @param destRow the row to create.
       * @param styleMap -
       */
      public static void copyRow(HSSFSheet srcSheet, HSSFSheet destSheet, HSSFRow srcRow, HSSFRow destRow, Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {   
          // manage a list of merged zone in order to not insert two times a merged zone
        Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions = new TreeSet<CellRangeAddressWrapper>();   
          destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());   
          // pour chaque row
          for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {   
              HSSFCell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j);   // ancienne cell
              HSSFCell newCell = destRow.getCell(j);  // new cell 
              if (oldCell != null) {   
                  if (newCell == null) {   
                      newCell = destRow.createCell(j);   
                  }   
                  // copy chaque cell
                  copyCell(oldCell, newCell, styleMap);   
                  // copy les informations de fusion entre les cellules
                  //System.out.println("row num: " + srcRow.getRowNum() + " , col: " + (short)oldCell.getColumnIndex());
                  CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = getMergedRegion(srcSheet, srcRow.getRowNum(), (short)oldCell.getColumnIndex());   

                  if (mergedRegion != null) { 
                    //System.out.println("Selected merged region: " + mergedRegion.toString());
                    CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(mergedRegion.getFirstRow(), mergedRegion.getLastRow(), mergedRegion.getFirstColumn(),  mergedRegion.getLastColumn());
                      //System.out.println("New merged region: " + newMergedRegion.toString());
                      CellRangeAddressWrapper wrapper = new CellRangeAddressWrapper(newMergedRegion);
                      if (isNewMergedRegion(wrapper, mergedRegions)) {
                          mergedRegions.add(wrapper);
                          destSheet.addMergedRegion(wrapper.range);   
                      }   
                  }   
              }   
          }   

      }   

      /**
       * @param oldCell
       * @param newCell
       * @param styleMap
       */
      public static void copyCell(HSSFCell oldCell, HSSFCell newCell, Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {   
          if(styleMap != null) {   
              if(oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()){   
                  newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());   
              } else{   
                  int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();   
                  HSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);   
                  if(newCellStyle == null){   
                      newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();   
                      newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());   
                      styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);   
                  }   
                  newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);   
              }   
          }   
          switch(oldCell.getCellType()) {   
              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:   
                  newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());   
                  break;   
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:   
                  newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());   
                  break;   
              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:   
                  newCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);   
                  break;   
              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:   
                  newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());   
                  break;   
              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:   
                  newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());   
                  break;   
              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:   
                  newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());   
                  break;   
              default:   
                  break;   
          }   

      }   

      /**
       * Récupère les informations de fusion des cellules dans la sheet source pour les appliquer
       * à la sheet destination...
       * Récupère toutes les zones merged dans la sheet source et regarde pour chacune d'elle si
       * elle se trouve dans la current row que nous traitons.
       * Si oui, retourne l'objet CellRangeAddress.
       * 
       * @param sheet the sheet containing the data.
       * @param rowNum the num of the row to copy.
       * @param cellNum the num of the cell to copy.
       * @return the CellRangeAddress created.
       */
      public static CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(HSSFSheet sheet, int rowNum, short cellNum) {   
          for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) { 
              CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);   
              if (merged.isInRange(rowNum, cellNum)) {   
                  return merged;   
              }   
          }   
          return null;   
      }   

      /**
       * Check that the merged region has been created in the destination sheet.
       * @param newMergedRegion the merged region to copy or not in the destination sheet.
       * @param mergedRegions the list containing all the merged region.
       * @return true if the merged region is already in the list or not.
       */
      private static boolean isNewMergedRegion(CellRangeAddressWrapper newMergedRegion, Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions) {
        return !mergedRegions.contains(newMergedRegion);   
      }   

  }
```

and:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;



 public class CellRangeAddressWrapper implements Comparable<CellRangeAddressWrapper> {

  public CellRangeAddress range;

  /**
   * @param theRange the CellRangeAddress object to wrap.
   */
  public CellRangeAddressWrapper(CellRangeAddress theRange) {
        this.range = theRange;
  }

  /**
   * @param o the object to compare.
   * @return -1 the current instance is prior to the object in parameter, 0: equal, 1: after...
   */
  public int compareTo(CellRangeAddressWrapper o) {

              if (range.getFirstColumn() < o.range.getFirstColumn()
                          && range.getFirstRow() < o.range.getFirstRow()) {
                    return -1;
              } else if (range.getFirstColumn() == o.range.getFirstColumn()
                          && range.getFirstRow() == o.range.getFirstRow()) {
                    return 0;
              } else {
                    return 1;
              }

  }

 }
```

Comment: What exactly happens with formulas?

Comment: The Excel sheet opens with FALSE in every cell, a formular has been in.
Maybe there is a problem with the cell type

Comment: do it  yourself . xlsx files are some xml files that had zip compressed.

Comment: If you click inside the cell, can you see the formula inside the Formula bar in Excel?

Comment: Yes, the formula remains

Comment: Have you tried [recalcuating the formulas](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) once you're done copying?

Comment: I tried it within Excel but there is no way to use the formulas, even copying them with Excel hasn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through the cells that has formula inside and set the Cell Type as "Formula":

Your copyCell method will be

```
public static void copyCell(HSSFCell oldCell, HSSFCell newCell, Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {   
      if(styleMap != null) {   
          if(oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()){   
              newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());   
          } else{   
              int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();   
              HSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);   
              if(newCellStyle == null){   
                  newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();   
                  newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());   
                  styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);   
              }   
              newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);   
          }   
      }   
      switch(oldCell.getCellType()) {   
          case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:   
              newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());   
              break;   
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:   
              newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());   
              break;   
          case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:   
              newCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);   
              break;   
          case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:   
              newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());   
              break;   
          case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:   
              newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());   
              break;   
          case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
              newCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA); //Add this line
              newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());   
              break;   
          default:   
              break;   
      } 
}
```