# How to clone an excel sheet from one workbook to another workbook using Apache POI and Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to copy a formatted excel sheet from one workbook to another which contains merged cells, font size, font color, font face.

I am able to copy all the sheets from multiple excel workbook to a single workbook but I am unable to get the formatting. Please help

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class CopyExcelSheets {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        //Excel sheet names to read from
        String [] excelSheets = {"Crystal1.xls","Crystal2.xls","Crystal3.xls","Crystal4.xls","Crystal5Complex.xls"};
        //Root folder from where the excel files are read
        final String ROOT_FOLDER = "C:\\demo\\shaji\\";
        //Output file name for merged excel file (consolidated file)
        final String OUTPUT_FILE = "C:\\demo\\shaji\\mergedOutput.xls";

        Workbook [] workbook = new Workbook[excelSheets.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < excelSheets.length; i++) {
            workbook[i] = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(ROOT_FOLDER + excelSheets[i]));
        }

        Workbook newWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        for(int i = 0; i < excelSheets.length; i++) {
            newWorkbook = CopyExcelSheets.copy(workbook[i], newWorkbook, "Book-" + i);
        }       

        //Write over to the new file
        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE);            
        newWorkbook.write(fileOut);

        for(int i = 0; i < excelSheets.length; i++) {
            workbook[i].close();
        }        

        newWorkbook.close();
        fileOut.close();
    }

    /*
     * Based on the implementation by Faraz Durrani on Stackoveflow
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333021/how-to-copy-one-workbook-sheet-to-another-workbook-sheet-using-apache-poi-and-ja
     */

    public static Workbook copy(Workbook oldWorkbook, Workbook newWorkbook, String bookName) throws IOException {
        // Need this to copy over styles from old sheet to new sheet. Next step will be processed below
        CellStyle newStyle = newWorkbook.createCellStyle(); 
        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        for (int i = 0; i < oldWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            HSSFSheet sheetFromOldWorkbook = (HSSFSheet) oldWorkbook.getSheetAt(i);
            HSSFSheet sheetForNewWorkbook = (HSSFSheet) newWorkbook.createSheet(bookName + "-" + sheetFromOldWorkbook.getSheetName());
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sheetFromOldWorkbook.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); rowIndex++) {
                row = sheetForNewWorkbook.createRow(rowIndex); //create row in this new sheet
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < sheetFromOldWorkbook.getRow(rowIndex).getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); colIndex++) {
                    cell = row.createCell(colIndex); //create cell in this row of this new sheet
                    //get cell from old/original Workbook's sheet and when cell is null, return it as blank cells. 
                    //And Blank cell will be returned as Blank cells. That will not change.
                    Cell c = sheetFromOldWorkbook.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(colIndex, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK ); 
                        if (c.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK){
                            //System.out.println("This is BLANK " +  ((XSSFCell) c).getReference());                            
                        }
                        else {  
                        //Below is where all the copying is happening. 
                        //First it copies the styles of each cell and then it copies the content.              
                        CellStyle origStyle = c.getCellStyle();
                        newStyle.cloneStyleFrom(origStyle);
                        cell.setCellStyle(newStyle);            

                         switch (c.getCellTypeEnum()) {
                            case STRING:                            
                                cell.setCellValue(c.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                                break;
                            case NUMERIC:
                                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {                             
                                    cell.setCellValue(c.getDateCellValue());
                                } else {                              
                                    cell.setCellValue(c.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                                break;
                            case BOOLEAN:
                                cell.setCellValue(c.getBooleanCellValue());
                                break;
                            case FORMULA:
                                cell.setCellValue(c.getCellFormula());
                                break;
                            case BLANK:
                                cell.setCellValue("");
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }    

        return newWorkbook;   
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you copy the file, for copying file read this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-file-in-java/

Comment: @SpringLearner, I need to consolidate all the sheets from multiple excel workbooks including complex reports into a single workbook. I am facing issues only with complex reports. I need to automate this task, i.e. different reports are generated at regular intervals and my task is to read those reports including complex reports (sheets) and consolidate it into a single workbook and email it. Your suggestion to copy simple text file may not work for excel workbook. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: Formatting is achieved using CellStyle and CellStyle definition is defined in workbook. It means you need to copy styles from source workbook to destination workbook. Problem is - there is no setCellStyle method in Workbook, createCellStyle and getCellStyle exist only

Comment: @VikasSachdeva, thank you for throwing light on the non-existence of setCellStyle method. It is greatly appreciated. Is there any way we can clone the sheet from source workbook to destination workbook? Any help or pointers will be of great help. Thank you

Comment: @ShajiKalidasan, Just I research about it and found that cloneStyleFrom() method should copy the formatting also. I am surprised why it is not working at your end. Please note that cells merging can not be copied by cloning cellstyle

Comment: @VikasSachdeva, thank you for letting me know about the problem when copying the merged cells. In my case, I have to copy merged cells. I will try to see how I can clone or copy merged cells too. Thanks for your time. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I go with this link.i found solution.This link is very useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903539/how-to-copy-a-excel-sheet-into-another-workbook-using-apache-poi-for-java